# How Do I render an ng-container or ng-template without *ngIf?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I need to add the `tappable` directive to the `ion-card` component inside a custom component. I use an `@Input() myInputBool`, something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myInputBool">
    <ion-card>
        <ng-container render="myContent"></ng-container>
    </ion-card>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!myInputBool">
    <ion-card tappable>
        <ng-container render="myContent"></ng-container>
    </ion-card>
</ng-container>

<ng-container #myContent>
    This is my content
</ng-container>
```

Of course it does not work because there are no "render" option. So far my workaround was adding an inexistent variable in the ng-container

```
<ng-container *ngIf="thisVariableDoesNotExist else myContent"> </ng-container>
```

But it feels bad and hacky. Is there a better way to this?

Comment: why do you use want to pass `myContent` to `render` to `ng-container`?

Comment: @Maximus I just want to use `#myContent` in both cases without repeating all the code.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would use `ngTemplateOutlet` instead of `render` option:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myContent"></ng-container>
```

See also

- https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#how-to-use